Object reference not set to an instance of an object after removal of page from Navigation Stack and navigated to other page
When I manipulate the navigation stack while loading another page, the application crashes. For example, suppose I have Page1 and Page2 in the navigation stack, and I navigate to Page3 from Page2. While initializing the Page3 object, I remove Page2 from the navigation stack. After Page3 finishes loading, the application crashes.
MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
    while (pageElementType != endPageType)
    {
        if (pageElementType == startPageType)
        {
            removePageIndex = index + 1;
        }
        else if (removePageIndex > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // If we comment below line of code of removal page then app doesnt get crashes after navigation to the next page
                **navService.RemovePage(navService.NavigationStack[removePageIndex]);**

                index--;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exception 
                Common.Log.Error($"{nameof(ManipulateNavStack)}", ex);
            }
        }

        index++;

        if (index < navService.NavigationStack.Count)
        {
            pageElementType = ((BaseViewModel)navService.NavigationStack[index].BindingContext).PageType;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
});

Getting below exception in iOS app only:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.NavigationRenderer.ParentingViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController.
Full Path: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.NavigationRenderer.ParentingViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent) at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 61 at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 96 at xxxxx.Mobile.Program.Main(String[] args

I tried removal of page from navigation stack on Mainthread.

I do not see Page1, Page2 and Page3 anywhere in the code. I do not see what are the starting values of the variables you use in the while cycle. I do not have any clue what this while cycle is trying to do. Not even a method name to give me a hint. I do not see when this code is being called. There is nothing to go on, really.

@H.A.H. While navigating to Third page app is getting a crash.
Please find sample project here:
https://github.com/PramodMAUI/iOSCrashWhenManipulatingStack/tree/main

@H.A.H.Please refer this sample project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/PramodMAUI/iOSCrashWhenManipulatingStack/tree/main
While navigating to Third page app crashes. Please check at your end and let me know if you have any query.

After checking your code, without a doubt I can say, that my competence in this area is lacking. I do not have the tools at home, to debug the IOS sample you provided, do help me determine the cause of your problem. I will put some bounty. Maybe someone with better knowledge will see it.

Waaaait. Why RemovePage is calling RemovePage?

@H.A.H. We need to maintain a navigation stack for back navigation. On back button press we need to navigate to desire page that why we've removed unwanted page from stack to land on required page on back button.

try to remove Page2 after Page3 is loaded?

@PramodPatil I recommend Stephen's answer. I am using the same navigation and code organization.

@BhavaneshN I tried remove Page2 after Page3 is loaded, but not worked.

This issue is linked with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/25726 and can only be reproduced on iOS platform using Visual Studio 17.13 Preview 1(8.0.93 & 8.0.83 & 8.0.60 & 8.0.40). Please follow up there.

I did a code review and made the following changes:

Reinstated the .NET MAUI Shell Navigation
Added CommunityToolkit.Mvvm
Provided your view models using dependency injection

As to your specific navigation, I can make use of backward navigation using ".." in the route, i.e.

Shell.Current.GoToAsync("FirstPage")
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("SecondPage")
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../ThirdPage")

For full working code see either:

My fork: https://github.com/stephenquan/iOSCrashWhenManipulatingStack
My PR: https://github.com/PramodMAUI/iOSCrashWhenManipulatingStack/pull/1

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=net-maui-9.0


Thank you for taking your time to review the code and provide sample. I also consider this the right architecture for MAUI Apps. Whether or not this answer gets accepted, I consider it a solution to the problem.

@H.A.H. - When we remove the page from stack, then only app crashes. We want to stick with default navigation service and no need to use shell navigation. As App will not crash if we don't remove the page from stack.

@PramodPatil Shell is the default navigation. I am using it from day one. There are so many specifics. Do you know that you can get the Navigation object from the MainPage and from the Shell? You can push and pop no matter where you got it. But if you got it from the main page, navigate and try to pop a page, you get exception? To make matter worse - it doesn't even happen all the time. Why is this happening? Who knows. Maybe even the guys who designed the MAUI navigation have no idea. My point is that there is a price to pay, when not sticking to the path...

@H.A.H. The existing project has more than 100 views and view models. And we have implemented business logic by removing pages from the stack in many places, so replacing the existing navigation with the shell will be time-consuming. So we need to continue using the navigation we've already used. It was working properly earlier, but recently we have been experiencing crashes when removing pages from the navigation.
